# How does Fleming's Functions of Several Variables compare to other texts?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

How does the book *Functions of Several Variables* by Wendell Fleming compare to texts like Spivak *Calculus on Manifolds*, Munkres *Analysis on Manifolds*, C.H Edwards *Advanced Calculus of Several Variables*? I know one difference is that Fleming uses Lebesgue integration in his integration chapter. But in terms of difficulty and clarity of proofs, is Fleming's text on the same level as the other mentioned texts?

I have also read good things about Hubbard and Hubbard *Vector Calculus*, but is this text on the same level as Fleming's text?
Another question I have is: Does Fleming's text cover as much calculus on manifolds as Spivak and Munkres?

I am mainly looking for a text that presents proofs in a clear and complete way, that avoids skipping steps in proofs as much as possible.

Thanks in advance